# Confused by until

Tags: tenses

Which question is correct? Please help me as I'm completely confused.

> Tony ________ to have children until his little daughter was born. After she won his heart, he decided he wanted a big family.
>
> A. didn't want
> B. hadn't wanted

This is a multiple choice question from *Understanding and Using English Grammar Workbook, 3rd edition* by Betty Schrampfer Azar. To me, both A and B seem correct and I don't know which option I should delete.